# How to find if LEFT JOIN joined an actual row, or placeholder NULL values?

Tags: sql, left-join

Suppose I issue a query like this:

```
SELECT a.x, b.y FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

I also want to know if a row from `b` is actually joined or there are just placeholder `NULL` values supplied by *`LEFT`*`JOIN`. I guess I can determine it comparing values of `a.id` and `b.id` in the result, but is there a way to do this in the query itself?

I.e. I'd want something like

```
SELECT a.x, b.y, b_is_actually_joined FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

where values in the column `b_is_actually_joined` are 1 or 0 (for example).

Answer (score 3):

Just check for NULL b.id:

```
SELECT a.x, b.y, b.id IS NOT NULL AS b_is_actually_joined 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

For Oracle SQL you can use NVL2 function:

```
SELECT a.id, b.*, NVL2(b.id, 1, 0) AS b_is_actually_joined 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/5ef64/10)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work on Oracle Database, fails with *ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected*.

Comment: @doublep added Oracle version

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Ms Sql Server:

```
select CAST((coalesce(b.id, 0)) as bit) as b_is_actually_joined FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON b.id = a.id
```

I am unaware of a standard SQL solution for this

Comment: No dbms is specified, and bit is not an ANSI/ISO datatype.

Comment: Sort of works if `bit` is replaced with something like e.g. `number` (not quite 0 or 1, rather 0 and non-0, but this is still OK). Kinda ugly though.